# Magento2.3 cart does not updated when adding product to cart

Tags: magento2.3, mini-cart

I'm facing an issue on my Magento 2.3 website when I'm adding the product to the cart. I'm getting the success message ('Product Name' has been added successfully), but the mini cart on the top right count does not get updated to (1) and when the mouse hovers to it the box is showing empty with the message 'You have no items in your shopping cart'.

When I look at exception.log or system.log I do not see any error that could cause this only error I see is related to search ›

[image]

Hoping someone might have a suggestion on what would cause this. we have not made any edits to any of the cart or mini cart phtml or functionality files.

Answer (score 0):

go to admin panel and enable it

```
admin -> stores -> configuration -> sales -> checkout -> my cart -> display cart summary -> display number of items in cart
```

Comment: thank you @bestestefan . When I go to that location there are no options shown. I tried changing to all the different store views I have but the admin panel just shows no optons?

Answer (score 0):

This should be related to the minicart not getting updated via customer data load call. On times developer do not think of Full page caching and overwrite this section with normal html code.
Then if the page gets cached this value remains as is as its delivered from cache.
So first check by disabling cache if the issue still persist.
Or go to cart page and see if the cart has data.

This is more of an issue as template work was not done following Magento guidelines. All customer data is to be treated as private data and using AJAX it should be populated .You should enablet block hint and then check which block then compare that block with he original theme code.

Comment: Thank you. When I click the actual cart icon and go to the cart my items are there. It seems just the mini cart and icon are not updating.

Comment: This is more of an issue as template work was not done following Magento guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

Overwrite/copy copy `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml` into your theme at `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[yourtheme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Add below code by changing `"bindSubmit": false` to `"bindSubmit": true`.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this can fix your issue.
Happy coding!!! :)